# Can the Canon EX III RT trigger an EX II?

Tags: canon, flash, hotshoe-flash

Can a Canon EX III-RT trigger an EX II?

I tried to conect them but was not unsuccessful. Is it possible to connect them at all?

Comment: Do you mean the 430EX III-RT and 430EX II? There are other "EX II" models such as the 580EX II.

Comment: Having a programming background, where for almost everything has some open source solution or a protocol is public available I found the flash receiver situation pretty disappointing. Even the same manufacturer is unwilling of providing backward compatible remote triggers for its products. After buying expensive canon flashes I switched to Yongnuo, for the much lower price you get a similar product but don't feed Canon the cash for the IMHO overpriced flashes. Buy the Yongnuo YN-E3-RT trigger and for the old flashes buy the YNE3-RX trigger. This way you should be able to trigger both flashes.

Answer (score 2):

No. The presence of a radio receiver in the flash is denoted by the *RT* in the model name. Models without an *RT* in their name do not have radio receivers.

You can either:

- Attach a radio receiver to the EX II flash. The [Yongnuo YNE3-RX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TGUR6TS) is such a receiver that is compatible with the 480EX II, 580EX II, YN568EX II, and other E-TTL capable flashes.

or

- Use a master flash with *optical* communication to the off camera flash. Unfortunately the EX430 III-RT is not capable of being an *optical* master, only a *radio* master. If you have a 580EX II you can use it as an *optical* mater to trigger the 480EX III-RT *optically*, but not by radio.